# Django Rest Framework with Cookiecutter

Tags: django-rest-framework, cookiecutter-django

I'm doing rest api with django rest framework and i wanted to use cookie cutter but there are lots of libraries for django rest based on cookie cutter and i don't know which is the most correct. Which cookie cutter should i use? And maybe it isn't necessary to use it?

Answer (score 1):

How familiar are you with Django Rest Framework?

I like to use it a lot, but I structure my things in a slightly unique manner, so I have my own cookiecutter (apparently like lots of other people).

If you are newer to Django, just go ahead and use the [startproject command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project).

If you are more familiar with Django, either find a cookiecutter that works for you, or make your own.